# Can I get value from mysql table and set it as variable?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

[image: attribute_description]

I have attribute_description like in the image :

on table I have for `cap_tabel` values: `d, lt, lu, amb, coada`

I want to get them and make it variable and set the value equal to the attribute_id.

eg:

```
$d = 1; 
$lt = 2; 
$coada = 9;
```

I think i can create a `function.php` file where this variables are created and use them where is needed.

Is this possible or I have to create a script where I name the variable myself and set it the right value like:

```
$amb_ext = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT attribute_id FROM attribute_description WHERE cap_tabel='amb'"));
$amb = $amb_ext['attribute_id'];
```

What do you think is the best solution?

In the end I want to create a product table where in `th` will be value from `cap_tabel` and in `td` to get the right value with the correct `th` cell

Comment: Not only is it the best solution, it is the *only* solution.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```php
$res = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT attribute_id, cap_tabel FROM attribute_description");
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $var = $row['cap_tabel'];
    $$var = $row['attribute_id'];
}
// you now would have variables $d, $lt, etc
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT attribute_id, cap_tabel FROM attribute_description");

while ($aValue =  mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ${$aValue['cap_tabel']} = $aValue['attribute_id'];
}

echo ' $d = ' . $d . ', $lt = ' . $lt . ', $coada = ' . $coada;
```

To get result like this :

```
$d = 1, $lt = 2, $coada = 9
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` will return an array, you wouldn't be able to do `fetch_assoc()` on `$oData` in your example. BTW, this is very similar to my answer but I got downvoted :(